# How to insert argument in awk script?

Tags: awk

I'm writing a shell script which shut down some services and trying to get its `pid` by using the following `awk` script.
However, this awk script can't get `pid`. What's wrong with that?

```
ps -ef | awk -v port_no=10080 '/[m]ilk.*port=port_no/{print $2}'
```

The result of `ps -ef` is like this:

```
username   13155 27705  0 16:06 pts/2    00:00:00 /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/bin/ruby /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/bin/milk web --no-browser --host=example.com --port=10080
```

This process is working with a different port argument as well, so I want to kill the process only working on `port=10080`.

The `awk` script below works fine, but when I specify the port no using `awk -v` like the above, it doesn't work well.

```
ps -ef | awk '/[m]ilk.*port=10080/{print $2}'
```

> awk version: GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: You may pass a whole regex in a variable: `awk -v port_no="[m]ilk.*port=10080" 'port_no{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for pattern matching with `/../` does not work with variables in the regular expression. You need to use the `~` syntax for it.

```
awk -v port_no=10080 '$0 ~ "[m]ilk.*port="port_no{print $2}'
```

If you notice the regex carefully, the regex string on the r.h.s of `~` is under the double-quotes `".."` except the variable name holding the port number which shouldn't be under quotes, for the expansion to happen.

Answer (score 1):

This task is easily accomplished using `pgrep`:

```
$ pgrep -f '[m]ilk.*port=10080'
```

Have a look at `man pgrep` for details.